# heroku app cant access from other devices

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I deployed a web app to Heroku yesterday and it seemed to work if I access the URL from my machine. However I was not able to access from any other devices on the same AND different network.

Comment: It is a confusion. Use this to check the availability of your web https://www.site24x7.com/ping-test.html

Comment: can you add the log file by using the command heroku logs -a appname

Comment: Have you tried adding https:// or http:// vise versa?